# I cannot change the progressbar's progress when i am setting progressbar max and min value

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

How to change the progressbar's progress color when you have set max and min value of progressbar. i have a progressbar and try to set max value as 15 and min value as -5. i want to show progress from -5 to 0 as progress and change the color of progress as red and show green color as 0 to 15 to the progressbar.

```
    <style name="CustomProgressBarReturnRange" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">4dp</item>
    </style>

   <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/returnProgress"
        style="@style/CustomProgressBarReturnRange"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="15"
        android:min="-5"
        android:progress="0" 
        tools:progress="20" />
```

Comment: Is it mixed color or after zero fully green!?

Comment: after zero it will be green color and before zero it will be red color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <style name="CustomProgressBarReturnRange" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_return_range_progress</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">4dp</item>
    </style>

<ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/returnProgress"
       style="@style/CustomProgressBarReturnRange"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:max="15"
       android:min="-5"
       android:progress="0" />


if (progressBar.progress <= 0) 
{
  progressBar.progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED)
} 
else if (progressBar.progress > 0)
{
  progressBar.progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Gradient drawable

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient
                    android:centerColor="#0C8110"
                    android:centerX=".4"
                    android:endColor="#045C07"
                    android:startColor="#C13C3C"
                    android:type="linear" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Linear drawable

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/progress">
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:width="80dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <size android:height="20dp" />
                    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:start="81dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <size android:height="20dp" />
                    <solid android:color="#1AFF00" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>

    </clip>
</item>
```

Your progressbar like this

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="15"
        android:min="-5"
        android:progress="10"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/your_drawable"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:id="@+id/mProgressBar"/>
```

Comment: where you have used this Gradient drawable and linear drawable?

Comment: Are you new to android? Create a drawable file in the res drawable folder. If you want gradient mixed color use it or only 2 colors use linear drawable

Comment: anyways i found the solution for this.